# get value from viewbag property in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller, viewbag

i need to assign value from viewbag property to javascript variable

I have gone through some of the posts and created the code as per that ..

```
var selectedID = null;
@if (ViewBag.Section != null) {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        selectedID =ViewBag.Section ;
    </script>
}
```

But the Problem is that it is not accepting the `ViewBag` Property inside script and displaying syntax error . Most of the posts has this format of solution ,

I have tried solution like :

1.

```
@{selectedID =ViewBag.Section ;}
```

2.

```
@if(ViewBag.DoAboutTab != null)
{
    var doAboutTab ="something";
} else {
    var doAboutTab ="something_else";
}
```

this solution is not assigning value to variable outside the `@{}` code
I am able to set constant value but not `Viewbag` Property by this solution

3.`selectedID = '@ViewBag.Section' !== @ViewBag.Section;`

this solution is also no working when `@ViewBag.Section` is `null`

how can I fix the script problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var selectedID = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Section));
</script>
```

If `ViewBag.Section` is not defined then you will get:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var selectedID = null;
</script>
```

and if for example ViewBag.Section equals to `Some nasty escaped " string` then you will get a properly encoded value which will not break your javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var selectedID = "Some nasty escaped \" string";
</script>
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    var selectedID = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Section));
</script>.............Json saved me , thanx